# Returning List of completable future with Optional object

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I'm trying to return a list of completable future with something like as shown below,

```
List<CompletableFuture<Optional<ModelObject>>> collect = 
            listOfModel.
            stream().
            map(modelObject -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                    ()-> {
                        try {
                                return   callMethodWithReturnTypeOfOptional<ModelObject>(modelObject);
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            LOGGER.error("Something bad happened");
                            return null; // what should be returned here?
                            // return Optional.<ModelObject>empty(); 
                        }
                    }
            , executor)).
            collect(Collectors.<CompletableFuture<Optional<ModelObject>>>toList());
```

Is there a better way to handling exception here?
Returning Optional.empty();  is a good practice?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not clear why `callMethodWithReturnTypeOfOptional` returns an `Optional` *and* throws exceptions, but if we assume that returning an empty optional and throwing an exception have different meanings, we should not discard that information. So the answer is, you should not catch the exception at all, so that the `CompletableFuture` can report it. If the method in question declares *checked* exceptions, just catch, wrap and rethrow them:

```
List<CompletableFuture<Optional<ModelObject>>> collect = 
    listOfModel.stream()
    .map(modelObject -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        ()-> {
            try {
                return callMethodWithReturnTypeOfOptional(modelObject);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                throw new CompletionException(e);
            }
        },
        executor))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using `CompletionException` as wrapper exception has the advantage that the `CompletableFuture` will not wrap the exception in another `CompletionException`, so this exception type is a natural choice within an action passed to a `CompletableFuture`.

Note that you can avoid capturing lambda expression in a natural way here:

```
List<CompletableFuture<Optional<ModelObject>>> collect = 
    listOfModel.stream()
    .map(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
    .map(f -> f.thenApplyAsync(
        modelObject -> {
            try {
                return callMethodWithReturnTypeOfOptional(modelObject);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                throw new CompletionException(e);
            }
        },
        executor))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If the method does not throw *checked* exceptions, this code simplifies to

```
List<CompletableFuture<Optional<ModelObject>>> collect = 
    listOfModel.stream()
    .map(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
    .map(f -> f.thenApplyAsync(Owner::callMethodWithReturnTypeOfOptional, executor))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're correct, it does not make sense to have that redundant exception block and thanks for that simplified code!